# When will execution plan of a query change after I update statictics or create indexes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-execution-plan

I run following query in SSMS:

`SELECT * FROM MyView v WHERE EXISTS WHERE exists (...)`

Based on the actual execution plan, I create an index and update some statistics.

When I run the query in SSMS again, will it calculate fresh execution plan?
If no, what is the optimal way?

Comment: option(recompile)

Comment: afaik changing any referenced objects eg updating statistics automatically invalidates any cached execution plan so it will be recompiled on next execution.